# Problems using click trigger in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I used a trigger because the "click" command was not recognized in JavaScript, but it does not work.

```
document.querySelector("#size > option:nth-child(2)").click();
```

1. `$("#size > option:nth-child(2)").trigger("click") or $("#size > option:nth-child(2)").trigger("change")`
2. `$(document).on("click","#size > option:nth-child(2)", function(){ return $(this).val(); });`

Both 1 and 2 don't work. Is there a solution??

Comment: `$` implies jQuery, though not necessarily. Are you looking for a native or jQuery solution?

Comment: Yes, Is there a solution?

Comment: Do you get any error in console?

Comment: no errors. but, click event does not work.

Answer (score 0):

**In JS you can use below code for click event**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onmouseover="myFunction()">

<script>
// On mouse-over, execute myFunction
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myCheck").click(); // Click on the checkbox
}
</script>
```

**If you want to use Jquery then for Jquery you can use below code**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onmouseover="myFunction()">
    
    <script>
  $( "#myCheck" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
    </script>
```

Comment: OP's problem mention qualifiers, hence `#size > option:nth-child(2)`. Your solution however only looks at an id `#myCheck`. You might want to delete your answer as it is not the answer.